# Kony Datagrid Export

Tags: csv, datagrid, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, temenos-quantum

Is there any way to export data from a Datagrid to a CSV file or some kind of Excel format in Kony Visualizer?

I'm developing the application for a Desktop platform. There was a similar question asked earlier by someone else on Kony Base Camp, but it was never answered. Here is the unanswered question I'm referring to, particularly question 2.

https://basecamp.kony.com/s/question/0D56A00000RZXw7SAH/reg-pdf-viewingexporting-options-for-desktop-and-spa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the platform-specific FFI libraries. You can utilize Kony Fabric to create a service that exports excel, word, or PDF documents.